# How to merge two requests when there are only 9 dimensions allowed

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-api

I use the following code to build a GA report based on 19 dimensions and two metrics.

```
var request = analytics.Reports.BatchGet(new GetReportsRequest
{
    ReportRequests = new[] {
        new ReportRequest{
            DateRanges = new[] { new DateRange{ StartDate = "2021-01-01", EndDate = "2021-01-31" }},
            Dimensions = new[] {
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:transactionId" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:campaign" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:source" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:medium" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:landingPagePath" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:adDistributionNetwork" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:operatingSystem" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:mobileDeviceBranding" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:userBucket" },
                /*new Dimension{ Name = "ga:referralPath" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:fullReferrer" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:keyword" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:adGroup" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:adSlot" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:adPlacementUrl" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:adDestinationUrl" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:sessionsToTransaction" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:daysToTransaction" },
                new Dimension{ Name = "ga:dateHour" },*/
            },
            Metrics = new[] { new Metric{ Expression = "ga:users" }, new Metric{ Expression = "ga:sessions" } },
            ViewId = "123456789"
        }
    }
});
GetReportsResponse response = request.Execute();
var dt = DataHelper.GetReportAsDataTable(response.Reports[0]);
```

As we know, Google does not allow more than 9 dimensions per request. So I might as well have to break each of my requests into three.

The key dimension for me is `ga:transactionId` and this is the one I want to be included in every request because that's what I base my report on. Every row should contain a `ga:transactionId`.

But now I don't know how I should merge all my dimensions in one table. Different combinations of dimensions lead to a different number of rows.

Does anyone know how one can get the logic right for a specific date interval?

Comment: What library do you use to form these requests?

Comment: @BNazaruk `Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4`

Answer (score 0):

See how you indicate that the key dimension is the ga:transactionId? That's supposed to be unique then for each of the metrics. Just make sure you include it in all three calls and then you JOIN your tables ON that transaction id just like you would typically do in SQL. Programming-wise it may be even easier to do it through SQL in case you already have it hooked up. Well, maybe something like a small local SQLite.

The different number of rows is to be debugged really. It may be due to the fact that not all transactions have all dimensions set, but that would open a possibility for you to not getting all transactions, so I would suggest pulling all transactions with no dimensions and making sure the cardinality of them is the same as the joined table.

Also consider splitting the metrics into two separate requests. It can help with debugging in case you encounter more bugs.

Comment: Yes, I will include `ga:transactionId` in every call. It's the different number of rows that confuses me. The thing is, only two of the dimensions above are in the same "Scope" as  `ga:transactionId` and the others come from other scopes. Still, Google does not complain about them according to this page  https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/ But then I wonder if it's this that is causing the diff, then one should only get dimensions and metrics that are sitting under the same scope? I don't know. What would you say?

Comment: No, mixing scopes is not an issue. Think about it as always getting hits. No matter the scope, your real scope in the data is always hits when you get it. If the dimension is Session, then all hits from this session will get the same value. If the dimension is User, then all hits from all sessions of this user will get the same value for the dimension. Mixing scopes is fine. Make sure google doesn't sample the data. Maybe try a big query export to check how the data really looks, it may make it easier.

Comment: My client hasn't added any billing information to the account. So, I don't think I have access to BigQuery. But it's good to know that mixing scopes is not an issue. I should dig deeper into understanding why I get a different number of rows based on the combination of dimensions.